# How Can I Change the VirtualBox VM that Docker is Connected To?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, boot2docker, docker-machine

When I start up the Docker Quickstart Terminal, it automatically stands up a virtual machine in VirtualBox called "default", and connects to it. I have a second VM running boot2docker, however, that I would like to use instead of the "default" one (let's call it "myVM").

I would like to change the Docker Terminal's connection over to myVM, so that I can issue commands like "docker images" or "docker ps" without having to specify the IP address, port etc. (so I don't have to do something like "docker -H 192.168.99.105:2376 blah"). How can I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To connect your shell to the new `myVM` machine.

```
eval $(docker-machine env myVM)
```

This sets environment variables for the current shell that the Docker client will read which specify the TLS settings. You need to do this each time you open a new shell or restart your machine.

Comment: If the vm hasn't been created by `docker-machine` then it will need to be added. It's probably easier to `create` a new one with the `virtualbox` driver than setup a connection via the `generic` driver.